# Make Screenshot and Screen Record result Blur at some view

Tags: java, android

Hi guys i wanted to make a screenshot & screen record like all streaming app, where they only blur/blacken the screen only in certain views, such as video views.

This is an example of a screenshot & screen record that I want, does anyone know how to make it?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XNVux.png)

I've tried to find out how to do it and have tried using FLAG_SECURE but the results I get are not able to take screenshots.